# JQuery: Selecting entire Column values from a table

Tags: jquery

Problem with the code. Both versions are below. Fixed & problem version. I want any optimized way.

// Use of #resultTable in a loop again is optimized way?. Its working fine.

```
$("#resultTable tr").each(function (i, row) {
    colValues[i] = $('#resultTable tr:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')> td:nth-child(2)').html();
});
```

// Loop selecting another table on the same page where #resultTable is. Not working

```
$("#resultTable tr").each(function (i, row) {
    colValues[i] = $('tr:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')> td:nth-child(2)').html();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `map()` at this context,

```
var colValues = $("#resultTable tr td:nth-child(2)").map(function(){
  return this.textContent;
}).get();
```

There is no need to iterate and construct the array. You can do it with `.get()`.